# Arp behavior on non requesting user for response

Tags: cache, arp

If we imagine we already have a valid cache for a pair in computer B and then composer A asks about the same pair and computer C responses with the pair information, what would happen here to computer B which already included the pair, would it update the cache or ignore it, since it wasn't its request? What exactly would happen in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is not destined for itself, it checks if the sender IP is in the cache, if it is in the
cache then it updates MAC of this IP with the new one received.